# how to concat and combine two rdd into one in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I get two `RDD` and want to concat and combine into one `RDD` as follows:

```
rdd_1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', ]
rdd_2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', ]

# concat and combine these two rdd into one
rdd = ['a1_b1', 'a2_b2', 'a3_b3', 'a4_b4', 'a5_b5']
```

I know I could convert these two `RDD` into `DataFrame` and concat it in `spark.sql` like follows:

```
df = df.withColumn('col1_col2', concat(col('col1'), lit(' '), col('col2')))
```

But it is not efficient enough for billons level samples.
So I want to know if there is a quicker way in `RRD` programming.

Comment: what is the rule to combine "a1" with "b1" ? you use the "1" ? imagine an RDD as a bag of marble. there is not predefined order in it. So first element of a list will not combien automatically with the first of another list. you need to define a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think looking to zip and join:

```
rdd_1.zip(rdd_2).map(lambda x : '_'.join(x)).collect()
```

Or without the `lambda`:

```
rdd_1.zip(rdd_2).map('_'.join).collect()
```

---

Example:

```
rdd_1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', ])
rdd_2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', ])

rdd_1.zip(rdd_2).map(lambda x : '_'.join(x)).collect()
```

---

```
['a1_b1', 'a2_b2', 'a3_b3', 'a4_b4', 'a5_b5']
```

Answer (score 1):

create rdds out of lists then do the zip on two rdds and then iterate this and concat using map and join.

```
rd1 = sc.parallelize(['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', ])
rd2 = sc.parallelize(['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', ])
rd1.zip(rd2).map(lambda x: x[0]+'_'+x[1]).collect()
rd1.zip(rd2).map(lambda x: '_'.join(x)).collect()
rd1.zip(rd2).map('_'.join).collect()

['a1_b1', 'a2_b2', 'a3_b3', 'a4_b4', 'a5_b5']
```